# bit data type in C language

Tags: c, gcc

I want to create a **bit datatye** in c language. I tried creating it using a structure with bitfield

```
struct bittype {
    unsigned int value:1;
};
typedef struct bittype bit;
```

But the problem with this is I have to use variables like

```
bit statusVariable;
statusVariable.value = 1;
```

How can i define a variable directly like,

```
bit statusVariable;
statusVariable = 1;
```

Comment: Could you just use [`bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean)?

Comment: Of course, either your struct or `bool` will use at least a byte.  If your goal is to do something like `bit bitarray[256];` and only use 8 bytes, you can't do that.  Maybe you should explain what you hope to achieve by having such a type in the first place; it's sounding like an XY problem.

Comment: The smallest addressable unit is a byte. Therefore, it is impossible to create a data type with a size of only 1 bit. However, you can set and retrieve individual bits from an integer variable using bitwise operations. In C++, these bitwise operations are handled internally by [`std::vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool), but there is no such thing in C.

Comment: `bit datatye` note that your bit datatype takes at least 2 bytes, most probably 4 - as many bytes as `unsigned int` needs.

Comment: you can only pack multiple bits into a byte. It's not possible to define a type with size equal to a bit

Comment: `#define BITON(var) var.value = 1` ... and in your example you'd do `bit statusVariable; BITON(statusVariable);`

Comment: What problem does this solve? Have you invented a 1 bit CPU? If not then simply use either `bool` or `uint8_t`.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Some architectures include operations to set, clear, or branch based upon the state of individual bits in memory; implementations specialized for such architectures often include a "bit" data type as an extension.  It would have been useful if the C Standard had included a Boolean type whose semantics were consistent with those of existing extensions, which implementations could either store using a non-addressable bit or byte, whichever was more convenient in the architecture, but unfortunately it includes no such type.

Answer (score 4):

Bits cannot be individually addressed only bytes.

```
struct bittype {
    unsigned int value:1;
};
typedef struct bittype bit;
```

The size of your structure will be the same or larger than the size of the `unsigned int`

If you define

```
bit eightBits[8];
```

It will not define the array of bits only the array of structures. It will have the size of `8*sizeof(bit)` which will be at least `8*sizeof(unsigned int)`.

If you want to define an object which can only have the value of `0` or `1`, the best way is to use `bool` type, as `bool` can only have value `0` or `1` despite the assigned value

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
    bool x = 1;
    printf("%d\n", x);
    x = 100;
    printf("%d\n", x);
    x = -100;
    printf("%d\n", x);
    x = 0;
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

will output

```
1
1
1
0
```